# Elegant way to aggregate and compute percentages in sql?

Tags: sql, aggregate, presto

I have a table of `user, product, count` that tells what the user purchased and how many times ("count").

I would like to know what is the "average basket" of a user, that is for each product what percentage it represents for the user.

e.g

```
user1,fruits,4
user1,water,2
user2,fruits,3
user2,food,9
```

so I would get

```
user1,fruits,0.6666  // = 4 / 4+2
user1,water,0.3333  // = 2 / 4+2
user2,fruits,0.25  // = 3 / 3+9
user2,food,0.75  // = 9 / 3+9
```

and later

```
fruits,0.45  // = 0.666+0.25 / 2
water,0.16  // = 0.33/2
food,0.38  // = 0.75/2
```

I have used

```
select t1.user as user, t1.product as product, max(t1.c) / max(t2.c) as ratio

from (
  select user, product, count(*) as c
  from table
  group by user, product
) t1
join (
  select user, count(*) as c
  from table
  group by user
) t2
on t1.user=t2.user
group by user, product
```

to get the first table, and then a `select product, avg(ratio) ... group by product` on that table.

Things work but I wonder if there was a more efficient / better way to do it?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: @RadimBača it is on presto

Answer (score 1):

I always use `window functions` to calculate percentages:

Reference: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66373/6

```
SELECT
  user,
  product,
  c,
  sum(c) over(partition by usr) sc,
  c / sum(c) over(partition by usr) per
FROM (
  SELECT usr, product, count(*) c
   FROM tablex
   GROUP BY usr, product
) t


CREATE TABLE tablex (
  usr varchar(32),
  product varchar(32)
);

INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'x');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'z');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'z');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'z');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'z');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('a', 'z');

INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'x');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'x');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'x');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'y');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'z');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'z');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'z');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'z');
INSERT INTO tablex VALUES ('b', 'z');
```

Comment: what is the difference (in terms of performance) between a join and a over ...? I'm not an expert but it seems there is still the need to do 2 queries

Comment: I think `over` runs faster than `join`. Because using `over` the second query runs on a "temporary" table and there is fewer data to compute (the data was already aggregate by the first query). But, you always can use DBMS debugger to ensure wich query runs faster. Ex: PostgreSQL (http://thoughtbot.com/blog/reading-an-explain-analyze-query-plan)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code and check the execution plan, I am sure the performance has been improved.

```
 select user, product, CAST(count(*) AS decimal(18,4)) / (select count(*) 
               from table t2 where t2.user = t1.user) 
 from table t1
 group by user, product
```

Comment: I check the execution plans and they are similar but the query code gets simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select user, product, count(*) as c,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by user) as ratio
from table
group by user, product;
```